# Parsing string and getting value in TCL

Tags: regex, tcl

I've string like this a sample one  what I need is parse through the string and get the value of a parameter  for example value of -type is Eth, so just the string next to the string I give.

card-1-3-1   3   -Number  2  -type  Eth  -config   Yes  -GEPorts 3

Answer (score 2):

```
set s {card-1-3-1 3 -Number 2 -type Eth -config Yes -GEPorts 3}
dict get $s -type
# -> Eth
```

By default, `card-1-3-1` becomes a key in the "eyes" of the `dict` command, but as long as that isn't a problem you don't need anything more complex than this. All the keys must have following values (i.e. the string must be a proper, even-sized list where the items are in key-value order).

Documentation: [dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: @user3126850: you might be using an obsolete version of Tcl. The `dict` command was added in Tcl 8.5, back in 2007. If you are using an older version, please upgrade: Tcl 8.4 and older are no longer supported for either security or bugs. If you can't upgrade, there is a pure-Tcl replacement for `dict` that can be used in Tcl 8.4.

Comment: The pure Tcl version of `dict` doesn't have quite all the good properties of the 8.5 one, but it might be good enough. Though ___upgrade___ is the official message.

Comment: How to handle if the key (-type) is not present ?

Comment: @Manoj: sorry, I'm having wetware problems and am rarely here. The dict get command by default errors out: you can catch that or use dict exists to look for the key beforehand.